# How to pick single and multiple images from gallery?

Tags: android, image, image-gallery

I want to pick single and multiple images from  gallery, I have tried below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
```

but it allows only multiple images, I can't select single one. I want pick single as well as multiple images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any default way to pick multiple images from android Gallery. You have to make your own media picker for the same. Please refer following link to get source code for picking multiple media. [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zh87udn3vt06yq/MultipleMediaPicker.zip?dl=0)

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer, and people may wish to delete it on the basis that it is brief and not self-contained. Is it possible to add the contents of that link into the question itself? The link is fine as well, but it is good if a copy is reproduced here.